# How to Extract Dates in DateRangeField in Django

Tags: python, django, date

I'm trying to extract the dates in the DateRange field in django. I'm trying to see if a date is within the range of that DateRange but I'm unable to extract the dates in DateRange. Here's a sample:

```
'date_range': DateRange(datetime.date(2017, 2, 17), datetime.date(2017, 2, 18), '[)')
```

So I'm trying to get the first date and the second date and check if a certain date is within that range of DateRange.

How do I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the range values through `.upper` and `.lower` properties. E.g., `my_object.date_range.upper`.

Comment: This seems to be the only place where it is documented.

Comment: Thanks. May I know how to add dates in this field?

Answer (score -2):

if you want to check that a whether a particular date is in a date range or not you can compare the dates

```
from datetime import date
>>> start = date(2017, 02, 1)
>>> end = date(2017, 02, 28)
>>> curr = date.today()
>>> curr >= start and curr <= end
True
```

Comment: I kinda know that already. My question was how do I "Extract" the dates from a DateRangeField in my Django database. The DateRange field is formatted like the one I've shared above. I've tried for looping and indexing but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: django does not have a field named DateRange. which field you are referring here?

Comment: Specifically, they are referring to `DateRange` in psycopg2.extras, which helps Django work with Range Fields along with Postgres. https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.DateRange